# Turbolinks vs JS MVC Frameworks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

We have applied EmberJS as a framework and using Rails 3.2 looking to migrate to Rails 4.0
A lot of push is being done by Rails community for turbolinks, on one side our site works well with the client side framework. And EmberJS gives a good support to write the custom code on the ends where we need one.

My question is how people perceive turbolinks as a way to make dynamic pages. Is going along with turbolinks implicitly meaning we must have as lean as possible Javascript (which means any JS framework is left redundant). So, how do we see would be the growth/support of the JS frameworks and would turbolinks become a defacto.

Is it the right time to start scale up for turbolinks and what are the good references.

Answer (score 3):

Turbolinks is not going to replace ember. This is really an apples to oranges comparison.

Turbolinks isn't a way to make dynamic pages, it's just a way to make your site faster by replacing the body content.

If you're already using Ember you should simply ignore turbolinks.